# Are Redundant Properties Bad Code Smell in C#?

Tags: properties, dependency-properties

I have a custom class in a library that gives properties for 3D location: X, Y, and Z (to be specific, they are dependency properties so the developer can animate them individually). Because I would like the developer to be able to take advantage of WPF's Point3D animation capabilities, I have also provided a Position dependency property.

Here are the specifics:

- Whenever X, Y, or Z, is updated, Position must be updated
- Whenever Position is updated, X, Y, and Z must be updated

This does not cause any problems since my property change callbacks are only executed when the property actually changes, avoiding an infinite loop. Though, it does add a bit of overhead when setting a property value. My question is: Is this bad code smell? It seems Microsoft uses a similar technique with the Rect3D class (X, Y, Z, and Location properties).

Thanks in advance